# Changes made in Feature file is not reflected in Feature.cs file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, feature-regression

I have few Feature files whenever I make any changes in feature file and try to run, the changes are not reflected in run.

When I checked this, I found out that Feature.cs file is not updated with the changes made in Feature file.

I tried build, rebuild, clean solution but not helpful.
I am using specflow version 2.2.1
Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3):

Got this fixed by following below:

We have to set SpecFlowSingleFile Generator to true

Tools > Options > SpecFlow > General > Legacy > Enable SpecFlowSingleFile Generator - True

Comment: Thanks! this also works for VS 2019 and Specflow 2.2